# which method to override this path /user/4/station in controller with sails js API

Tags: orm, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Just want to know which method i need to override to access to this route:

```
/user/4/station
```

I override this method  User.findOneByStation generated by sails, but still return the ressource, i need to make computation on this ressource before return json, and no idea where sails handle this route.

Comment: If you respect Rest standards, this route should call `StationController.findByUser`. It would return a list of stations

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly (if you are looking for something else, please clarify)

routes.js

```
'GET /user/:id/station': 'UserController.getByStation'
```

UserController.js

```
module.exports = {
  getByStation: function(req, res) {
    // Do computation

    // Prepare and return response e.g.
    res.ok({ id: 1 });
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanx for ur reply, this is not what i want exactly, i want to overidde the default behavior of the generated getter method by waterline, no need to add a route, just want to overidde the method, but don't find it actually.

Comment: I think what you looking is configuration of routes.js file